# Is there any way apply the rules to history emails with EWS

Tags: exchangewebservices, rules

Is there any way apply the rules to history emails with EWS?
When calling [UpdateInboxRules (Create Rule)](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/updateinboxrules-operation?redirectedfrom=MSDN),I want the rule to take effect immediately.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't retrospectively apply a Rule using EWS (Like you can in Outlook) if you want to do that you need to create you own code to enumerate the messages and apply whatever logic is in the rule to messages.

Comment: Okay.I want to enumerate the messages, I should search messages firstly.But when i using findItems with SearchFilter to filter messages, it can't filter them as rules.Is there any way better to do it?

Comment: depend how complex you rule is if you doing anything at the recipient level then you will need to add some more logic in eg loadproperteisfromItems to load the recipient collection and do item level processing of the messages